# xmlstarlet selecting a node with a specific attribute value

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, attributes, xmlstarlet

I am new to all of this so please forgive me if the answer is totally obvious!  I have an XML document I downloaded from NCBI and I am trying to extract the host information from each entry, which looks a little something like this (but much more deeply nested):

```
<OrgName_mod>
    <OrgMod>
        <OrgMod_subtype value="strain">2</OrgMod_subtype>
        <OrgMod_subname>Mvs/Jiroft.IRN/14.15/1[B3]</OrgMod_subname>
    </OrgMod>
    <OrgMod>
        <OrgMod_subtype value="nat-host">21</OrgMod_subtype>
        <OrgMod_subname>Homo sapiens</OrgMod_subname>
    </OrgMod>
</OrgName_mod>
```

I've had success using the following:

```
xml sel -t -v //OrgName_mod/OrgMod[2]/OrgMod_subname -n file.xml
```

But the problem is that sometimes there is more or less information in the OrgMod nodes and the host isn't always in the second position. So I've tried just about every version of this to try and select the host node specifically:

```
xml sel -t -m //OrgMod/OrgMod_subtype[@value=nat-host] -v ../OrgMod_subname -n file.xml
```

I want to select the OrgMod_subtype node with the nat-host attribute and then subsequently print the sibling (?) OrgMod_subname node with the species name.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

```
 //OrgMod[OrgMod_subtype/@value = 'nat-host']/OrgMod_subname/text()
```

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

I also get this error when I try to use [last()] - am I missing something?

Comment: I am using OXgen. It works fine. this expression returns: Homo sapiens.

Comment: Try wrapping your xpath in quotes:  `xml sel -t -m "//OrgMod[OrgMod_subtype/@value = 'nat-host']/OrgMod_subname/text()" -n file.xml'`

Comment: I figured it out.  TextEdit was "smart-fixing" my quotation marks and bash didn't like it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing, the only way to refer a sibling as by going to its parent. For example, the following is an error when I tested:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//OrgMod/[OrgMod_subtype/@value='nat-host']/OrgMod_subname/text()" file.xml
Invalid expression: //OrgMod/[OrgMod_subtype/@value='nat-host']/OrgMod_subname/text()
compilation error: element for-each
xsl:for-each : could not compile select expression '//OrgMod/[OrgMod_subtype/@value='nat-host']/OrgMod_subname/text()'
```

So I improvised by going downwards by **../** , and this work:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//OrgMod/OrgMod_subtype[@value='nat-host']" -v "../OrgMod_subname/text()" file.xml
Homo sapiens~
$
```

My **xmlstarlet** version is:

```
$ xmlstarlet --version
1.6.1
compiled against libxml2 2.9.1, linked with 20904
compiled against libxslt 1.1.28, linked with 10129
$
```